# MySQL replacing Timezone naive dates by aware. [Python Django Models]

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, timezone

I have a MySQL database with millions of rows of data. I also have an application responsible for having persisted that data in the DB.

In my application settings, I'm using a specific timezone:
ex: TIME_ZONE = 'America/Montreal'.

I'm NOT using the USE_TZ = True parameter (that's why I say I have TimeZone unaware datetimes in my DB).

The problem is that my server is in Montreal but people who accesses it are spread around the world and, logically, the dates they see are subjected to bad interpretation.

So, I've read some stuff about using pytz and django.utils.timezone but, first of all, I think I should refresh my database data entries adding the timezone "particle" that would let me then "cast" my datetimes to the timezones of each user (in presentation mode).

This is my approach, because from the creation of the DB until now the server was always in Montreal, and the datetimes are for sure, from that timezone.
But someday, I may want to change the server location and consequently my TIME_ZONE settings, and I wish to be able to show the ancient datetimes casting "FROM" the truth timezone of which datetime was created..

Example of one of my python objects attribute wich is DateTime:
end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

Comment: simple fix: store all dates as UTC, then convert as needed based on the user's own TZ. this will be FAR more efficient than using every single tz in the sun in the same field.

Comment: yeah I know, but how do I refresh (update) the existing datetime in the DB entries (existing rows...)..
DB script? what should it consist? I don't mind doing it manually table by table...

Comment: presumably you'd be storing the tz somwhere, so `update yourtable set timefield=convert_tz(timefield, field_which_contains_timezone, 'UTC')` type of thing would do. Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Seems nice, will give it a try! Thank you both.

Comment: Implemented and worked like a charm! Now I have a timezone enabled site :)